# Classes and objects in Python (object overriding)

Tags: python

need a small help on this code

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self,other):
        print ("hello, %s" %(other)) <--- doubt

class CEO(Employee):
   def greet(self,other):
      print ("Get back to work, %s!" %(other))  <---- doubt
c1 = CEO("Emily")
e1 = Employee("bhargav")

c1.greet(e1)
e1.greet(c1)
```

I know if i change the variables in the highlighted lines to "other.name" i'll be getting the desired output as below.

```
Get back to work, bhargav!
hello, Emily
```

But if i just give "other" ill be getting the below output.

```
Get back to work, <__main__.Employee object at 0x0000021858C64FD0>!
hello, <__main__.CEO object at 0x0000021858C64F60>
```

Can you guys please explain me the importance of adding ".name" in the print statement.

Comment: In this case [`other`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) is a class instance. So you should use `.name` to get  its attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `c1.greet(e1)` you're passing `e1` which is `Employee("bhargav")` object of class Employee.

So when you print `"Get back to work, %s!" %(other)`, you're trying to print the object of Employee class and not the name attribute of that class.

If you want to print the `name` attribute of the object whenever you try to print the object, then You can override the `__str__()` function and provide your custom string representation for the object.

Something like this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def greet(self, other):
        print("hello, %s" % other)

class CEO(Employee):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def greet(self, other):
        print("Get back to work, %s!" % other)
```

Reference : [https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/courses/python/class/5/#**str**](https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/courses/python/class/5/#__str__)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `c1.greet(e1)` and `e1` is `e1 = Employee("bhargav")`, which is an object of **Employee class**.

Hence, you are getting output as `Get back to work, <__main__.Employee object at 0x0000021858C64FD0>!`

Doing `print(e1.name)` will print `bhargav` and doing `print(e1)` will just print the Employee object along with it's memory location (*0x0000021858C64FD0*).

To achieve what you are trying to do use `dunder __str__` in Employee class like this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def greet(self,other):
        print ("hello, %s" %(other)) #<--- doubt

class CEO(Employee):
   def greet(self,other):
      print ("Get back to work, %s!" %(other))  #<---- doubt     

c1 = CEO("Emily")
e1 = Employee("bhargav")

c1.greet(e1)
e1.greet(c1)
```

Output:

```
Get back to work, bhargav!
hello, Emily
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return result from object of a class then you need to declare it.
Using **repr**(for python2) or **str**(for python3 and python2).

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self,other):
        print ("hello, %s" %(other))
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

class CEO(Employee):
    def greet(self,other):
        print ("Get back to work, %s!" %(other))
    def __str__(self):
        return ("self.name")
c1 = CEO("Emily")
e1 = Employee("bhargav")
c1.greet(e1)
e1.greet(c1)
```

Now this will show desired output.